# To deploy an angular project

Tags: angular, azure-devops

I am trying to develop a vss web extension with angular...

I should refer a html file to create .vsix file.

But in angular, we use *ng serve* then our page is loaded in http://localhost:4200/ and I am in a big confusion how to upload a working vss-extension which is developed with angular.

By the way, I am able to successfully design basic html files and publish them without any problem.

Could you lead me what direction I should go?

Comment: You should use ng build and if you use local node_modules ( node node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build )

Comment: I used ng build and output is filled to dist klasor. But I could not see anything when I open index.html in dist klasor

Comment: You should open it with the http-service for example https://github.com/http-party/http-server

Comment: If you do not mind, give me a little more detail, because I really do not have much experience with angular, web services, and about the world of web development. It will be so greate if you give me a hand, my mail addres is, akcakhusnu@gmail.com, thank you

Comment: Actually here is the situation, If I did not get it wrong, content of the dist klasor needs to be uploaded to the web server and index.html inside it,is refererred as entry point. I did this, but some other problems occured then, so now I end up with using react and it is working now, thank you for your answer and for your effort to help but I could not make it useful in this my problem

Comment: Hi @husnu you could move your comment to below as a reply and mark yourself. Which will also help others in the community. In case they get stuck with same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **[Visual Studio Services Web Extension SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk)**. Some  steps for reference:

1. Create typings.json

Code:

```
{

  "globalDependencies": {

    "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160929162922",

    "knockout": "registry:dt/knockout#0.0.0+20160914182733", 

    "q": "registry:dt/q#0.0.0+20161004185634",

    "require": "registry:dt/require#2.1.20+20160919185614",

    "tfs": "npm:vss-web-extension-sdk/typings/tfs.d.ts",

    "vss": "npm:vss-web-extension-sdk/typings/vss.d.ts"

  }

}
```

2. Run typings install command to install necessary package (in typings folder)
3. Open your typescript file and reference (e.g. /// )

For example:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />

import Controls = require("VSS/Controls");

import VSS_Service = require("VSS/Service");

import TFS_Build_Contracts = require("TFS/Build/Contracts");

import TFS_Build_Extension_Contracts = require("TFS/Build/ExtensionContracts");
```

4. Create tsconfig.json

Code:

```
{

  "compilerOptions": {

    "module": "amd",

    "target": "ES5",

    "outDir": "dist/",

    "rootDir": "enhancer/",

    "moduleResolution": "node"

  },

  "files": [

    "[your ts file]"

   ]

}
```

5. Run tsc command

You can check modules (e.g. VSS/Controls) in these files vss-web-extension-sdk\typings\vss.d.ts, tfs.d.ts, rmo.d.ts.

Also take a look at below links which maybe helpful:

- [Develop a web extension for Azure DevOps Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=azure-devops)
- [Using TypeScript for your VSTS extension walk trough](https://www.ericksegaar.com/2017/11/27/using-typescript-for-your-vsts-extension-walk-trough/)

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your effort to help. Now here where I end up with, If I did not get it wrong, content of the dist klasor needs to be uploaded to the web server and index.html inside it,is refererred as entry point. I did this, but some other problems occured then, so now I end up with using react and it is working now, thank you for your answer and for your effort to help but I could not make it useful in this my problem